# How to put border bottom only on last-child of dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Can somebody please give me advice or tell me how to add border to only my first and last child of my sub-menu.The problem with CSS last-child and First-child is that my menu li is constructed from 2 UL's with li elements.What i wanna say is,when i put `ul li:last-child` because my li with name test2 have only 1 child ul it targets both first ul of my menu and that happens:http://prntscr.com/dbxpeo

It targets first ul of my other other Li element which have 2 ul's in it.
I want border only on bottom and only on top of first and last li elements,so it become as background  when you hover on the menu,something like [This!](http://prntscr.com/dbxqtr)Here is my CSS:

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
13. Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-header .menu-new{
position:relative;
margin-bottom:1.5em;
padding:0px;
font: 67.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:0.95em;
font-weight:bold;
width:63%;
height:80px;
left:245px;
}
.menu-new ul{
background:transparent;
list-style:none;
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border-radius: 15px;
  -ms-transform: skew(-15deg,0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg,0deg);
  transform: skew(-15deg,0deg);  
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 16px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 16px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
box-shadow: inset 0px 16px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
.menu-new li {
display:block;
right:-2%;
float:left;
border-right:1px solid black;
position:relative;
height:auto;
}
/*
.menu-new li:first-child{
border-left:1px solid black;
}
*/
.menu-new li > a:after{
content: "\37";
font-family: "ElegantIcons";
}
.menu-new li a:only-child:after, .menu-new li li a:after{
content:"";
}
.menu-new li .sub-menu li ul li:last-child, .menu-new li .sub-menu li:last-child {
border-bottom:12px solid black;
border-rdius:5%;
}
/*
.menu-new li > ul >li >ul >li:last-child{
border-bottom:20px solid black;
border-radius:7px;
}
*/
.menu-new li a{
display:block;
font-weight:normal;
line-height:80px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px 30px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
}
.menu-new li a:hover{
background:#8c8c8c;
opacity:0.8;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.menu-new li ul{
display:none;
height:auto;
position:absolute;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
border:0px;
width:200px;
z-index:200; 
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg,0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg,0deg);
  transform: skew(0deg,0deg); 
}
.menu-new ul li:hover a{
background:#000000;
color:#FFFFFF;
opacity:0.8;
text-decoration:none;
}
.menu-new li:hover ul{
display:block;
background:transparent;
color:transparent;
}
.menu-new li li{
display:block;
position:relative;
right:1px;
top:10%;
float:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:200px;
background:transparent;
}
.menu-new li li li {
display:block;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:10%;
float:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:200px;
background:transparent;
}
.menu-new li:hover li a{
background:#000;
color:#FFFFFF;
opacity:0.7;
}
.menu-new li li li a{
text-align:center;
}
.menu-new li ul a:hover, .menu li ul li:hover a .menu li li li:hover{
border:0px;
text-align:center;
color:#ffffff;
background:#8c8c8c;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
.menu-new{
display:none;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:1030px){
.menu-new{
top:80px;
}
.menu li{
background:#fff;
opacity:0.8;
}
.menu-new li> li> li{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
opacity:0.8;
}
.menu-new li >li > li:hover{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
opacity:1;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-new">
     <nav class="menu" role="navigation">
         <ul class="menu ul">
            <li>
             <a></a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a></a>                                                                        <ul>
                 <li>
                  <a></a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                    <a></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
           </ul>
                <li>
                  <a></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a></a>
                 <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a></a>
                  </li>
                 </ul>
                 </li>
                </nav>
             </div>
```

I am working on wordpress so i tried to reconstruct the HTML of the menu,i think its accurate.

Comment: What about `ul.menu > li:last-child` with `>` included

Comment: do u have any online demo or site url so i can have a look

Comment: I Will give you the site link,because i don't have a demo. http://shreddingnation.com/

Comment: HTML structure looks weird, why we have those nested sub menus instead of li ? can you share the screenshot of Menus structure in back end ?

Comment: Its wierd,for real i don't know why wordpress is doing it that way,there is no back end its only that:                                               
                                            `<?php wp_nav_menu(array (
                                                'theme_location'=> 'new-menu',
      'container' => '', 
      'items_wrap' => '%3$s' 
                                                )); ?>`
Php code,with which you are calling the already build in menu structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply this code

```
.sub-menu .sub-menu li:last-child{
 border-bottom: 12px solid red;
}
```

and remove this code

```
.menu-new li .sub-menu li ul li:last-child, .menu-new li .sub-menu li:last-child{
 border-bottom: 12px solid black;
}
```

**update**

see if this works for you

```
ul  ul > li:not(.menu-item-has-children) :last-child{
   border-bottom: 12px solid red;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is working just for the one with 2 ul's in it Here is Pictures:Menu with 2 Ul's http://prntscr.com/dby5at....Menu with 1 Ul http://prntscr.com/dby5gt

Comment: That did it mate,can you please explain how you did it,i mean what is that .menu-item-has-children, i can apply your code to my caret too,because as you see there are 2 arrows in sub-menu ;d THANKS btw <3

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:last-child` pseudo-class, this selector allows you to target directly the last element

```
ul li:last-child{ 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Adapt it as your needs, you can add multiple tag to fit to the HTML structure, like `ul li li:last-child` or `ul li:last-child li`

You can read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-of-type/)

Comment: Well i guess you haven't read all of my question.I cannot target it with last child,because it will target all of my dopdown li's becuase they are all childs of Ul elements... Wordpress makes it really hard

Comment: I read your question,. i just provides a generic solution, it's up to you to read link to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I used those method,but still didn't get the result i want i used:
`.menu-new .sub-menu:last-of-type li:last-child{
 border-bottom: 12px solid red;
}` and that is what happens:http://prntscr.com/dbyeax

Answer (score 1):

HTML structure looks weird, why we have those nested sub menus instead of li ? can you share the screenshot of Menus structure in back end ?